# Windows XP Freeze on Bootup

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machines, vmware-workstation

Every time I boot my minimal-install Windows XP virtual machine it takes 70 seconds of me looking at my windows desktop before I can actually use my mouse and/or do anything.

Is there a way I can fix my boot-time and/or diagnose what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use msconfig and turn off what is left and see if it continues to boot slowly.  If the VM is still loading slowly there are a couple of things you can check:
1.  VM disk configuration correct?
2.  Bad sectors on your Host system?
3.  Any sort of hidden process attempting to access the network within the VM (and the network is disconnected, thus causing a long timeout)?

Answer (score 0):

First :
- try to disconnect all devices (except Hard disk of course),
perhaps windows try to check a device or something else ?

Second :
- try with "bootvis" utilities that can display boot time report.

Yves.